# How to update the CollectionView cell that selected before and now Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I have a horizontal collection view.When user click on a photo,a UIView appear to cover the photo.Only 1 photo will can be selected in 1 time.Means that,if a photo is selected,if I click on another photo,the previous photo will back to normal.

I implement this code below:

```
 var previousSelectedIndexPath : IndexPath? 
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if previousSelectedIndexPath != nil {
            let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previousSelectedIndexPath!) as! photoCell
            previousCell.uiViewHeight.constant = 0
        }

        let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! photoCell
        currentCell.uiViewHeight.constant = 250
        previousSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
 }
```

What I get is,when the collection view first launch,it shown the behavior I want.But when I click on a photo,then scroll to left,then click a new photo again,it show error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

I think is the photo selected before is not appear on screen anymore,therefore it cant be update the constraints of the UIView of that photo.

I tried to implement this solution as well,but get the same error as well :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! photoCell
    cell.uiViewHeight.constant = 250    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! photoCell
    cell.uiViewHeight.constant = 0
}
```

So in this case,how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `cellForItem(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible, so doing a `as!` will clearly make it crash. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, add/remove your effect according to the indexPath, and in didSelect, reloadCellForItemAtIndexPath of the previous one (if it's visible, it will reload it, if not, won't do a thing).

Comment: @Larme can you please make an answer,so I can try it in my code

Comment: Something like that: https://pastebin.com/q56EEXPJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ken, don't force cast your `UICollectionViewCell`, your app could be crash.

Use safe code like that :

```
if let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? photoCell {
      // if succeed, do code
}
```